# Smarty with CiviRules

Tags: civirules, smarty

I have a template with Smarty strings.

If I send the email from inside CiviCRM, Smarty works fine (it shows "Cher Guillaume"):

[image]

If I send the same template using a CiviRule, it doesn't work:

[image]

although it attaches a .pdf file with Smarty Strings inside that also work fine.

Is there a reason related to CiviRule?

Any idea?

best Regards

Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a diffence in the way tokens behave in the Email or PDF API, as far as I know this has been fixed in the latest versions of the extensions Email API and PDF API. Can you check if you have these latest versions installed?

Comment: Hi Erik, E-mail API is 1.19 and PDF API is 2.4, so I guess up-to-date.

Comment: And the Smarty switch in your civicrm.settings is on? I assume you are not using a  token?

Comment: this is what I have in civicrm.settings :

/**
 * Enable this constant, if you want to send your email through the smarty
 * templating engine(allows you to do conditional and more complex logic)
 *
 */
if (!defined('CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 );
}

I don't use tokens just strings

Comment: I do recommend using tokens if at all possible :-). As far as the problem goes: I can not really say from a distance if this behaviour is still a bug or something is wrong in your specific installation or use case unfortunately...:-(

Comment: Ok I understand. This is not a major issue. How can I learn to use tokens?

Comment: How to use tokens: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/. How to create your own specific tokens: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/ and https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokenValues/. An example extension: https://lab.civicrm.org/partners/civicoop/mediwe/mediwecustomtokens

Comment: thanks Erik! just do it now! ;-)